# Is there a plugin that will strip a bit of text out of a string?

Tags: url, variable

I've got a variable like {current_url} which contains the full url of the page you are on.

I want to strip out the last segment from it.

Is there a plugin or native EE way of doing that?

Say that variable is example.com/me/you and i want to remove the "you" from the end, how would i do that?

Due to variable url segments, i can't do {segment_2}{segment_3}{segment_4} as "you" might be the second or third or fourth variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it, the brilliant @low strikes again with a great plugin called Low Replace!

Syntax like:

```
{exp:low_replace find="you" replace=""}{current_url}{/exp:low_replace}
```

Cool!

Comment: exactly what i was going to suggest.

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly that right now - AWESOME!

Answer (score 7):

Low's stuff is allways awesome. I was thinking of this, pretty awesome too. http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-string?

Comment: CE String is awesome and indispensable. It's like a Swiss Army Knife.

Answer (score 4):

You could also try [PHPStringFun](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/phpstringfun) and the str_replace function. PHPStringFun lets you run php functions on the template without enabling PHP.

It'll be overly complex for this but is useful if you need to do anything more than just replace text (or use any other phpfunctions).

Answer (score 2):

[Surgeree](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/surgeree) also does regex replace.